# adding top 10 to a leveling system leaderboard

Tags: json, discord, discord.js, fs, leaderboard

So I'm trying to add top 10 for my leaderboard  this is the code that I'm using for the leveling system and leaderboard but I dont know how to add the top 10 and I need it because when you type the command it just spams because a lot of people have talked so please help.

```
client.on("message", async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.channel.type === "dm") {
    return;
  }
  const dm = client.users.cache.get(message.author.id);

  if (!db[message.author.id])
    db[message.author.id] = {
      userid: message.author.id,
      xp: 0,
      level: 0,
    };
  db[message.author.id].xp++;
  let userInfo = db[message.author.id];
  if (userInfo.xp > 99) {
    userInfo.level++;
    userInfo.xp = 0;
    dm.send(
      new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle(
          `${levelup}Level up${levelup}\n${levelup}Level: ${userInfo.level} ${levelup}`
        )
        .setColor("#E2DF09")
        .setTimestamp()
    );
  }
  if (
    message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + "rank") ||
    message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + "level")
  ) {
    let userInfo = db[message.author.id];
    let member = message.mentions.members.first();
    let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("#E2DF09")
      .addField("Level", `${info}` + userInfo.level + `${info}`)
      .addField("XP", `${info}` + userInfo.xp + "/100" + `${info}`)
      .setFooter(
        `${message.author.tag}`,
        `${message.author.avatarURL({ dynamic: true })}`
      );
    if (!member) return message.channel.send(embed);
    let memberInfo = db[member.id];
    let embed2 = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor("#E2DF09")
      .addField("Level", `${info}` + memberInfo.level + `${info}`)
      .addField("XP", `${info}` + memberInfo.xp + "/100" + `${info}`);
    message.channel.send(embed2);
  } else if (
    message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + "leaderboard") ||
    message.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(prefix + "lb")
  ) {
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle("Leaderboard")
      .setColor("#E2DF09");
    const c = Object.entries(db).sort((a, b, d) => b[1].level - a[1].level);
    for (const [key, value] of c) {
      embed.addField(
        `\u200B`,
        `<@${value.userid}>\nLevel: ${value.level} | XP: ${value.xp}`
      );
    }
    message.channel.send(embed);
  }
  fs.writeFile("./db/database.json", JSON.stringify(db), (error) => {
    console.error();
  });
});
```

and also this is how the json file looks like
I use the userid for the leaderboard tag

```
{"630812692659044352":{"userid":"630812692659044352","xp":31,"level":32}
```

This is how the leaderboard looks like but I want to add the numbers next to the username and for the 1st, 2nd, 3rd i want to add like a trophy or something but its not working out on my side .

[image: This is how the leaderboard looks like]

Comment: Please show us how you store the user-level data

Comment: the json looks like this 
{"630812692659044352":{"userid":"630812692659044352","xp":31,"level":32}

Comment: I tried to answer, I didn’t get to test it on discord, but I tested it on an online code editor (except for the addField part)

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I think would work (I tested it on an online site)

```js
var ranks = {
'SOMEUSERID': {
userid: 'SOMEUSERID',
rank: 0,
xp: 45
},
'ANOTHERUSERID': {
userid: 'THEUSERID',
rank: 0,
xp: 70
}
}
//^^EXAMPLE RANKS, DONT ADD THESE^^
var leaderboard = []
for(const i in ranks) {
var person = ranks[i];
leaderboard.push(person)
}
//^^LOOP THROUGH ALL USERS^^
leaderboard.sort((b, a) => ((a.rank+1)*(a.xp)) - ((b.rank+1)*(b.xp)))

//^^SORT BY (RANK+1)*XP, in descending order^^

var ranksSorted = leaderboard.map(u => u.rank);
var xpSorted = leaderboard.map(u => u.xp)
var usersSorted = leaderboard.map(u => u.userid)
//ranksSorted, xpSorted, and usersSorted are synced
//...
//top 10 leaderboard within one string

var str = '';
for(let i = 0; i<=10 && i<leaderboard.length;i++) {
str += usersSorted[i] + '\n' + ranksSorted[i] + ' | ' + xpSorted[i] + '\n'
//YOU CAN ALSO ACCESS WHICH PLACE THEY ARE WITH i+1
}
```

So you don’t have to save it on string, instead of adding it to the string, you can do add embed field, like this:

```js
for(let i = 0; i<=10 && i<leaderboard.length;i++) {
someEmbed.addField(client.users.cache.get(usersSorted[i]).tag, ranksSorted[i] + ' | ' + xpSorted[i])
}
```

EDIT: rank*xp wouldn’t work well. 1*28 for example is more than 2*13. Do `Math.pow()`.

```js
leaderboard.sort((b, a) => ((a.rank+1)*(a.xp)) - (Math.pow((b.rank+1), 10)*(b.xp)))
//instead of the previous leaderboard.sort
```

This way, rank 1 xp 99 is less than rank 2 xp 1